# What does "macro annotations embedding in comments" mean in mcpp?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

In `mcpp.exe --help`

```
Options available with only -@std (default) option:
-@compat    Expand recursive macro more than Standard.
-3          Enable trigraphs.
-K          **Output macro annotations embedding in comments.**
```

So, what does 'macro annotation in comments' mean?

http://mcpp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mcpp-summary-272.pdf file available at SourceForge (link in question):

> Also
>   mcpp has a mode to output macro informations
>   embedded in comments. This mode allows you
>   to know macro calls and their locations on source
>   file from preprocessed output.

So, it leaves behind comments identifying the macros expanded, so that you can tell which source came from which macro.

### Illustration

#### Source (x.c)

```
#include <assert.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(argc != 0 && argv != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

#### mcpp x.c

```
#line 1 "/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x.c"
#line 1 "/usr/include/assert.h"
#line 42 "/usr/include/assert.h"
#line 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h"
#line 417 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h"
#line 1 "/usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h"
#line 418 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h"
#line 494 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h"
#line 1 "/usr/include/sys/_posix_availability.h"
#line 495 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h"
#line 43 "/usr/include/assert.h"
#line 61 "/usr/include/assert.h"


void abort(void)  ;

int printf(const char *  , ...);

#line 2 "/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x.c"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ((void) ((argc != 0 && argv != 0) ? 0 : ((void)printf ("%s:%u: failed assertion `%s'\n", "/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x.c" , 4 , "argc != 0 && argv != 0"), abort()) )) ;
    return 0;
}
```

#### mccp -K x.c (excerpt)

I omitted about 560 lines of not very informative output, but the main code is:

```
#line 2 "/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x.c"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /*<assert 4:5-4:35*//*!assert:0-0 4:12-4:34*/((void) ((/*<assert:0-0*/argc != 0 && argv != 0/*>*/) ? 0 : /*<__assert*//*!__assert:0-0*//*!__assert:0-1*//*!__assert:0-2*/((void)printf ("%s:%u: failed assertion `%s'\n", /*<__assert:0-1*//*<__FILE__*/"/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x.c"/*>*//*>*/, /*<__assert:0-2*//*<__LINE__*/4/*>*//*>*/, /*<__assert:0-0*//*<assert:0-0*/"argc != 0 && argv != 0"/*>*//*>*/), abort())/*>*/))/*>*/;
    return 0;
}
```

Or, with comments isolated one per line (manually):

```
#line 2 "/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x.c"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /*<assert 4:5-4:35*/
    /*!assert:0-0 4:12-4:34*/
    ((void) ((
      /*<assert:0-0*/
      argc != 0 && argv != 0
    /*>*/
             ) ? 0 :
    /*<__assert*/
    /*!__assert:0-0*/
    /*!__assert:0-1*/
    /*!__assert:0-2*/
    ((void)printf ("%s:%u: failed assertion `%s'\n",
    /*<__assert:0-1*/
    /*<__FILE__*/
    "/Users/jleffler/src/cmd/x.c"
    /*>*/
    /*>*/
    ,
    /*<__assert:0-2*/
    /*<__LINE__*/
    4
    /*>*/
    /*>*/
    ,
    /*<__assert:0-0*/
    /*<assert:0-0*/
    "argc != 0 && argv != 0"
    /*>*/
    /*>*/
    ), abort())
    /*>*/
    ))
    /*>*/
    ;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the bug in this implementation of the `assert()` macro?

*Hint*: the C99 standard says:

> #### §7.2.1.1 The `assert` macro
>
> The `assert` macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; it expands to a void expression.
>   When it is executed, if expression (which shall have a scalar type) is false (that is,
>   compares equal to 0), the `assert` macro writes information about the particular call that
>   failed (including the text of the argument, the name of the source file, the source line
>   number, and the name of the enclosing function — the latter are respectively the values of
>   the preprocessing macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` and of the identifier
>   `__func__`) on the standard error stream in an implementation-defined format. It
>   then calls the `abort` function.

The machine is running MacOS X Lion (10.7.1).