# preserve preprocessor directives as comments with `gcc -E`

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to achive something like this with `gcc -E`?

src.c:

```
z
#define FOO bar
z
```

actual preprocess result:

```
# 1 "src.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "src.c"
z

z
```

desired preprocess result:

```
# 1 "src.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "src.c"
z
/* #define FOO bar */
z
```

Comment: What kind of [XY](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341) [problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done directly, but if you really wanted this, you could pass the `-dD` option to cpp (via the gcc driver it might look like `-Wp,-dD`; then further process the output to turn the `#define`s into comments.

`-dD` tells the preprocessor to keep the `#define` directives in the resulting output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the defines as comments maybe you can study MCPP manual, I sort of remember there is an option for this.
At least `-C` preserves the comments, and `-K` is described as "embed macro annotation into comments".

https://linux.die.net/man/1/mcpp

[What does "macro annotations embedding in comments" mean in mcpp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303532/what-does-macro-annotations-embedding-in-comments-mean-in-mcpp)

If that doesn't work you'll have to make a parser. either use clang as a library and iterate on preprocessor tokens. Or do your own with AntlR (there are many ready to use C grammars)